# Access Mongoose Model with method from Model's Schema

Tags: oop, mongoose, models

I am wondering if this Mongoose Model scenario will work and am currently unable to test it.

```
var xSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Data: String
});

xSchema.methods.getData = function(ID){
    SSS.findById(ID, function(err, found){
        if(err) throw err;
        return found;
    }
}

SSS = mongoose.model('x', xSchema);
```

Will `SSS.getData()` return `Data` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my test codes, please make sure the first parameter of `mongoose.model` should be same as `SSS`, just as my codes show below.

```
var xSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Data: String
});
xSchema.methods.getData = function(ID, callback){
    SSS.findById(ID, function(err, found){
        if(err) throw err;
        else
            callback && callback(found);
    });
}
var SSS = mongoose.model('SSS', xSchema);


function findX() {
    var s1 = new SSS({data: 'dd'});
    // the `"56d7c1b29741d2982750c725"` is the `_id` of `{Data: 'test'}`
    s1.getData("56d7c1b29741d2982750c725", function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
}

function saveX() {
    var s = new SSS({Data: 'test'});
    s.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log('save sss successfully');
    });
}
```

The `xSchema.methods` define the [`instance method`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), maybe the `Statics` method would be better in your case

```
xSchema.statics.getData = function (ID, cb) {
```

Then you can access this method through

```
SSS.getData(ID, cb)
```